# Template Widget in Django 2.0 & Crispy form

Tags: django, django-forms, django-templates, django-crispy-forms, django-widget

I would like to change the way a widget is rendered in Django. I've read this guide https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/forms/renderers/ but still I can't make it working.

I've create this widget

```
class MultiChoiceFilterWidget(forms.widgets.CheckboxSelectMultiple):
    template_name = 'web_admin/partial/checkbox.html'
```

but it's not working in the sense that the default look-and-feel is displayed, there's no sign of my edits.

In `TEMPLATES` I've the folder `myproject.web` and the folder structure is `myproject/web/templates/web_admin/partial/checkbox.html`

What Am I missing?

(I also tried to put a file in `django/forms/widgets/checkbox_select.html` that is the file the widget is looking for, but still not working)

**edit**
in `settings.py`

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
   ...
    'web',
  ...
]
```

in `forms.py`

```
class MyChoiceForm(ModelForm):
        class Meta:
            model = MyModel
            fields = ('theField',)
            widgets = {
                'theField': MultiChoiceFilterWidget,
            }
```

**edit2**
Update the question to reflect the fact that this works for plain django, not with crispy form.

Comment: Are you using the MultiChoiceFilterWidget? As in do you have code somewhere that says something along the lines of `field_name = forms.SomeField(widget=MultiChoiceFilterWidget)`?

Comment: Is `web` an app in `INSTALLED_APPS`? If not you might need to set `FORM_RENDERER`. See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46835633/django-widget-template-override-does-not-search-in-the-project-template-director/46836189#46836189).

Comment: Yes for both questions, see the edit in the question

Comment: Your example code looks ok. If you show your real code it might show a problem that isn't in your example form.

Comment: it seems that it's a problem with crispy form.. removing the `crispy` it works. I'm filling in an issue to see how to solve it and update this question